# How to determine the lowest bound of current sensor sensitivity?

Tags: arduino, current, sensor

I would like to build current logger using Arduino. I am having hard time finding out and understanding the lowest bounds of current sensor sensitivity.

The following [link](https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2020/02/15/acs712-current-sensor-features-how-it-works-arduino-guide/) states sensitivity this way "66 to 185 mV/A output sensitivity". Does it mean that 1 Amp will generate 66 mV? Does it mean that the lowest I can go is 1/66 Amp, which will generate 1 mV? Now it brings question what Voltage can Arduino read? If Arduino can read up to 1 uV, does it mean that I can go even lower with the above sense like 1/(66*1000) Amp?

Overall I need fairly sensitive sensor 1 mA or less if possible. Could somebody recommend something?

P.S. I am very new to all of this.

P.P.S. Here is a [datasheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS712-Datasheet.ashx)

Comment: please update your datasheet link to the actual datasheet, not to the seller's webpage

Comment: Try to state "fairly sensitive sensor 1 mA or less" in different words. What is the minimum current you need to detect (lower values will read as 0) and the maximum current you need to measure?

Comment: The datasheet lists, if you bother to look beyond the 1st page, several sections on "performance characteristics" that are very different in terms of sensitivity. For example, the x05B seems more sensitive than the others. It's rated for about 5 A magnitude. If you need to measure milliamp-scale currents, you may find these devices "difficult."

Comment: What makes you think an Arduino can resolve 1 microvolt? I think that is optimistic by about 3 orders of magnitude. You should probably include a link to the datasheet for the exact Arduino model that you want to use; there are many different "Arduino" boards. Also, do you care about **accuracy** at all or just sensitivity?

Comment: I have no idea what Arduino to use, but let us try this one: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf
I would like to detect 1 mA, but if it is too optimistic than 50 mA. Accuracy matters of course, but I do not know what is the reasonable level that I can achieve with basic tools.

Comment: Uno uses 12-bit ADC with 3.3V ref, so min. V detectable =  1 mV approximately.

Comment: @MeenieLeis I think you mean Zero has 12-bit ADC, the UNO has 10-bit ADC [link](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/).

Comment: @user1700890 It would help to have more information. The datasheet in the microchip link corresponds to atmega328p microcontroller (uC) with 10-bit ADC. This uC is used in the UNO and has a 5V reference.  If you select the hall-effect sensor ACS712 (x05B variant), you get 0.185mV for 1mA through +IP and -IP terminals. 
This is an order of magnitude away from needed resolution.
I'd recommend selecting 12-bit Arduino, getting precise reference voltage, and perhaps using shunt resistor with amplifier (you could also use hall-effect sensor with amp).